# Raspberry cannot resolve hostname

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi

I installed Debian version 2 on a Raspberry Pi, and I'm trying to use the Internet on it, but every time I try it I get a message saying "Cannot resolve host name".

I was using the tutorial *[Configure Raspberry Pi Hardware to Mail IP Address Changes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/getting-the-raspberry_pi-ip-address.html)*, but it didn't work.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This is of-topic, but you are most likely missing a DNS server in /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: wow, "Debian 2" (codename *hamm*) was released in 1998; didn't know they had rpi's then :-). in any case @Martin is right: [sf] is about programming and your question is not. you might have more luck asing on [su] or the [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) SE-site

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Raspberry Pi config question, not a programming question. There is an answer on Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

Edit file `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Set the DNS server. Add this line: `nameserver X.X.X.X`. Search online for DNS server IP address for your country.

Comment: the resolv.con already have that line 8.8.8.8

Comment: change this 8.8.8.8 by a DNS server IP. try this [ http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/free-public-dns-servers.htm  ] to get DNS server IP. me from france I change the 8.8.8.8 by french DNS server and it works after.

Comment: `8.8.8.8` is a DNS server IP (run by Google). But if another works better, change it of course.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a provider router, put the router's IP address in file `resolv.conf` like MAKOUDA says.

```
nameserver X.X.X.X
```

Where X.X.X.X is your router's IP address.